# DataGrid: How do I programmatically select DataGrid ComboBox items, WITHOUT manipulating the GUI?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, combobox

I asked this before and have a solution that works:

[See Answer by srithar here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e73b6847-2e11-4e9a-a068-085232253685/wpf-datagrid-how-do-i-programmatically-select-a-combobox-item?forum=wpf)

Being new to XAML/WPF, that one was my instinctively preferred solution. However, experts keep on telling us: "DO NOT manipulate the GUI! Handle the **model** instead."

This is the relevant XAML code:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" Top Plate Thickness ">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Gauge, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Thickness"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding TopPlateThickness, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionChanged="ComboBoxLeft_SelectionChanged">
                <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Enabled}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

It currently supports the ability to disable menu items. This is the Code Behind:

```
static List<string> caliber = new List<string> { "0.3750", "0.5000", "0.6250", "0.7500", "1.0000" };


string left  = "";
string right = "";
PlateThicknesses(ref left, ref right, rnd);
Selectable top = new Selectable(left);
Selectable bot = new Selectable(right);


GridsModel gm = new GridsModel()
{
    OuterDiameter        = outerDiameter,
    InnerDiameter        = innerDiameter,
    TopPlateThickness    = top,
    BottomPlateThickness = bot
};


static void PlateThicknesses(ref string leftComboBoxIndex, ref string rightComboBoxIndex)
{
    int a = rnd.Next(7);
    int b = rnd.Next(7);

    if (a > b)
    {
        leftComboBoxIndex  = caliber[a];
        rightComboBoxIndex = caliber[b];
    }
    else
    {
        leftComboBoxIndex  = caliber[b];
        rightComboBoxIndex = caliber[b];
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class GridsModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public string Item                    { get; set; }
    public string Description             { get; set; }

    private int _Quantity;
    public  int  Quantity
    {
        get
        {
            return _Quantity;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Quantity != value)
            {
                _Quantity = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Quantity");
            }
        }
    }

    private int _QtyOfFound;
    public  int  QtyOfFound
    {
        get
        {
            return _QtyOfFound;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_QtyOfFound != value)
            {
                _QtyOfFound = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("QtyOfFound");
            }
        }
    }

    public double MaxBoltLoad             { get; set; }
    public int    NumberOfBolts           { get; set; }
    public double Separation              { get; set; }

    private double _Length;
    public  double  Length
    {
        get
        {
            return _Length;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Length != value)
            {
                _Length = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Length");
            }
        }
    }

    public double Gamma                   { get; set; }
    public double Beta                    { get; set; }
    public double OuterDiameter           { get; set; }
    public double InnerDiameter           { get; set; }

    public List<Selectable> Gauge         { get; set; }           // Gauche is "Left" in French

    private Selectable _TopPlateThickness;
    public  Selectable  TopPlateThickness
    {
        get
        {
            return _TopPlateThickness;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_TopPlateThickness != value)
            {
                _TopPlateThickness = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TopPlateThickness");
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Selectable> Caliber       { get; set; }           // The Right Stuff

    private Selectable _BottomPlateThickness;
    public  Selectable  BottomPlateThickness
    {
        get
        {
            return _BottomPlateThickness;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_BottomPlateThickness != value)
            {
                _BottomPlateThickness = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("BottomPlateThickness");
            }
        }
    }

    public double BoltCircleDiameter      { get; set; }

    private double _TemplateSetWeight;
    public  double  TemplateSetWeight
    {
        get
        {
            return _TemplateSetWeight;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_TemplateSetWeight != value)
            {
                _TemplateSetWeight = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TemplateSetWeight");
            }
        }
    }

    public double AnchorBoltSetWeight     { get; set; }

    private double _WholeAnchorCageWeight;
    public  double  WholeAnchorCageWeight
    {
        get
        {
            return _WholeAnchorCageWeight;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_WholeAnchorCageWeight != value)
            {
                _WholeAnchorCageWeight = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("WholeAnchorCageWeight");
            }
        }
    }

    public GridsModel()
    {
        Gauge = new List<Selectable>  {  new Selectable("0.3750"),
                                         new Selectable("0.4375"),
                                         new Selectable("0.5000"),
                                         new Selectable("0.6250"),
                                         new Selectable("0.7500"),
                                         new Selectable("0.8650"),
                                         new Selectable("1.0000") };

        Caliber = new List<Selectable> { new Selectable("0.3750"),
                                         new Selectable("0.4370"),
                                         new Selectable("0.5000"),
                                         new Selectable("0.6250"),
                                         new Selectable("0.7500"),
                                         new Selectable("0.8650"),
                                         new Selectable("1.0000") };
    }
}
```

Selectable Class:

```
public class Selectable : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _Thickness;
    public  string  Thickness
    {
        get
        {
            return _Thickness;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Thickness != value)
            {
                _Thickness = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Thickness");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _Enabled;
    public  bool  Enabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _Enabled;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Enabled != value)
            {
                _Enabled = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Enabled");
            }
        }
    }

    public Selectable(string thickness)
    {
        Thickness = thickness;
        Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Using debugging code I can see that the desired properties are actually being assigned the desired values, but the visual UI fails to display them.

TIA

Comment: Where is the `Gauge` property declared? and where is `TopPlateThickness` declared? post that code, too

Comment: @HighCore: Flattered?

Comment: The left column is base on `Gauge` and the right one on `Caliber`

Comment: If necessary, I could make a minimal version, the way I did before.

Comment: All your code seems fine, so far.

In order to change the `SelectedItem` in the `ComboBox`, simply change the value of the `TopPlateThickness` property in your model. Doing so, and because you're doing `NotifyPropertyChange()`, WPF will automatically update the `SelectedItem` in the UI to the corresponding value in the `ItemsSource` collection.

Comment: What is the behavior you're getting right now? the ComboBox keeps it's previous selection? Or does it stay blank? and what does the `SelectionChanged` event handler do?

Comment: The ComboBox is unaffected. It stays blank at startup time. By putting some **erroneous code** I can make the 1st. value of the List[0] to appear in all the ComboBoxes.

Comment: By **erroneous code** I mean that I have been playing with `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` and finally the ComboBoxes are not blank. I can place the lowest thickness in all Combos.

Comment: `It stays blank at startup time` - That's right, because your constructor does not set the `TopPlateThickness` to anything, and nowhere in the code you posted are you setting that either, so it's going to be null. WPF is doing exactly what you're telling it to =)

Comment: @HighCore: The model (aka properties) contains the desired values: All of them. All rows in two columns.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Your `new Selectable()` is not part of the `ItemsSource` collection, it doesn't work that way, you have to pick a valid value from within the collection.

Comment: @HighCore Sorry I accidentally dropped an anvil on you. No hard feelings?